# When is it better to populate an array with fixed index macros vs by incrementing an index?

Tags: c++

When would it be better to proceed this way

```
#define PREFIX_IDX 0
#define SUFFIX_IDX 1
#define ARRAY_DATA_SIZE 2

int data[ARRAY_DATA_SIZE ] = 0;

int main() {
  data[PREFIX_IDX] = 6;
  data[SUFFIX_IDX] = 19;
  return 0;
}
```

compared with

```
#define ARRAY_DATA_SIZE 2

int data[ARRAY_DATA_SIZE ] = 0;

int main() {
  uint8_t currIdx = 0;
  data[currIdx++] = 6;
  data[currIdx++] = 19;
  return 0;
}
```

I was told with small arrays it was better to use fixed macros, but I feel like it does not scale very well. What would be the general advice for this?

Comment: Depends on how you use it. If `data[0]` has a specific meaning (the prefix index), then using an index constant would be preferred. If `data` just holds a bunch of numbers without having a specific meaning, then incrementing an index would be preferred. But YMMV.

Comment: And named indexes doesn't need to be MACROs, `constexpr` index would do the job too.

Comment: If `PREFIX_IDX` contains a semantic meaning, then `data[PREFIX_IDX] = 6` tells you that you set `6` as a value for the prefix. With `data[currIdx++] = 6;` you only know that you set a certain index in your `data` to `6`, but you don't know if `6` at this position has any particular meaning.

Comment: Avoid Macros! And in this case I wouldn't use an array at all. I would use a struct something like this. struct my_data { int prefix_idx; int suffix_idx; }. my_data data{};
data.prefix_idx = 6; data.prefix_idx = 19;  (or my_data data{6,19};). That way your code much better explains itself

Comment: The code is mapping associated values. You should name the constant each time. It helps to ignore the fact that the keys are consecutive integer values. The value associated with `SUFFIX_IDX` is `19`. There is no benefit to using increments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid macros whenever possible, and it's possible in this case.  If you are using at least C++11 (and you should be), you can use `constexpr` to declare your magic constants at compile time:

```
static inline constexpr auto PREFIX_IDX = 0u;
static inline constexpr auto SUFFIX_IDX = 1u;
static inline constexpr auto ARRAY_DATA_SIZE = 2u;
```

That said, you need to match your code to the semantics of what you're doing. This makes your code more readable.   The size of the array doesn't matter.  What matters is if you've attached different meanings to different elements of the array.

You've attached a sematic tag of "prefix" to `data[0]` and one of "suffix" to `data[1]`.  Since elements of the array have magic roles, you should index them with your magic constants.

```
int data[ARRAY_DATA_SIZE];

int main() 
{
   data[PREFIX_IDX] = 6;
   data[SUFFIX_IDX] = 19;
   return 0;
}
```

Depending on how complex your actual code is, it might be better to forego the array entirely and use separate variables.  However, I've had code where you have to treat things as the same type of thing in one place and as different types in another, so an array is definitely OK.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Spencer said (don't use `#define`):

Actually, it would be best to use an enumeration type.  This idiom lets you have the benefits of named fields when you want to refer to a specific one, but also still lets you iterate over them if you want to process them all.

But, with a distinct enum type, you can wrap it in a class that implements `operator[]` and ensures that you use *only* those enumerations as subscripts, rather than arbitrary values.

Even if you don't do that, it serves to show that the names are related in a group, *and* it automatically increments them as you define them.

---

Also, `int data[ARRAY_DATA_SIZE ] = 0;` is confusing.  You are initializing an array with an int, and the special value zero at that.  This is *not* a pointer.  A global array of ints will be zeroed anyway.  So what is this for?  Is it a mistake?  Readers will wonder.

---

Of course, this could be an X-of-Y problem.  If you are incrementing as with:

```
  uint8_t currIdx = 0;
  data[currIdx++] = 6;
  data[currIdx++] = 19;
```

the right answer is to use an aggregate to do it all in one, not increment the subscript at all.

```
  constexpr int vals[] = {6,19};
  std::ranges::copy (vals, data.begin());
```

if you used `std::array` rather than the primitive array syntax, and you were always going to supply the whole thing, then you can just use a single normal assignment.

Comment: There are use cases for both.   The problem with an enum is that you should use a scoped enum whenever possible, and then you have to do conversions back to the underlying integer type everywhere.

Comment: If you are not imposing the strong typing, using an old-style enum will give the same results as individual named constants, but have the benefit of grouping and auto-numbering.

Comment: Agreed, What I *really* want is to be able to base an enum off another enum rather than just an integer type.  I often have a base class with "core" roles and a descendant with extended roles.

Comment: @Spencer yes, "inherit" the enum to extend it.  Plus have a built-in way to access the largest enum constant, rather than having to define a dummy `MAX` name, as that gets in the way when continuing/inheriting.

Comment: The "builtin" max would always have to be `2^n-1` because the standard says values up to the "largest bitset" that the named enumerators fit in are valid.  You would still need to declare your own "sequential" max.

Comment: @Spencer I mean have a way of querying what the largest declared enumeration constant of that type is.  I was not referring to the size of the underlying integer type!  Any useful system of introspection ([example](https://youtu.be/60ECEc-URP8?t=2130)) will provide a way to list the declared enumeration names and values; find the max of those.

Comment: yes, that would be the "sequential " max. The problem is, you'd have disagreement over which kind of max to use between different  people who wanted different things.

Comment: @Spencer disagreement:  you just have different functions.  The underlying integer type, and the max value of that, is something available at compile time _now_.

Comment: The max value of the underlying integer type is different from the max value of the enum's matching bitfield.  Some people still create enumerator values by ORing bits.

Comment: @Spencer I'm not disagreeing... people have to know when (by analogy) to call `capacity()` vs `size()` of a container, or any other case where there are multiple different things to know.  Plain introspection of what enumerations were defined will not tell you the intended use; that needs additional features such as attributes or conventions followed.  You can inherit from a class and do stuff all wrong; the compiler doesn't stop you.  Likewise, if extending an enum you have some responsibility for doing it correctly based on the design.